# Create individual tags from array of data - Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

so the output of the variable **result** from my device is an array with the JSON response below. I'd like to take the first value of each key and make it into an individual object so that I can send it to a mongoose database to save the results. How would I do this? The values in the keys are dynamic there could be 2 or 100 depending on what it finds.

```
[
{
    "Read_Count": [
        31,
        5,
        23,
        1
    ],
    "Antenna": [
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
    ],
    "EPC": [
        "300833B2DDD9014000000000",
        "E280116060000207B6C9E1E2",
        "300833B2DDD9014000000000",
        "E2801160600002096622B8C0"
    ],
    "Signal": [
        224,
        196,
        212,
        194
    ]
}
```

I'd like the output to be as follows:

```
{
   "Tags": [
    { "EPC":"300833B2DDD9014000000000", "Read_Count": 31, "Antenna": 1, "Signal": 224 },
    { "EPC":"E280116060000207B6C9E1E2", "Read_Count": 5, "Antenna": 1, "Signal": 196 },
    { "EPC":"E2801160600002096622B8C0", "Read_Count": 23, "Antenna": 1, "Signal": 212 } 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please post example output.

Comment: I have posted the example output

Comment: If the above json, is example output, can you post example input .

Comment: Update sorry now I understand what you both meant

Comment: This is actually just a JavaScript question; the fact that you're using node.js and mongodb are inconsequential to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So for each one of the objects in the array, you need to go through its keys and set the value of that key in your result to the first element of the array in that key's value.

```
var result = {
    'Tags': []
}
response.forEach(tag => {
    var resultingTag = {}
    Object.keys(tag).forEach(key => {
        resultingTag[key] = tag[key][0]
    })
    result.Tags.push(resultingTag);
}
```

('response' is your input array that you posted in your first code block, if that wasn't clear)

Comment: This only returned the results from the first set of values i.e: Tag: [ "EPC: 300833B2DDD9014000000000....... "] how do I return all the values?

Comment: If that's the output you got, you've somehow managed to push a string representation of a key value pair into an array. The code I posted couldn't possibly give that result. It works as written, the problem must be in your implementation of it. You could edit your question with the code you're running, otherwise there's no way to tell what you're doing wrong.